# How to read current source html from a webpage using Java/Perl/Python (e.g. after editing it using the js console)

Tags: java, python, html, perl, parsing

I realize this looks like a duplicate question, but it's not!(as far as I know, and I've searched a lot...) So for the last few days I've been trying to get the HTML content of my whatsapp web application but using the input stream reader provided by java seems to not give me the full html code. The URL I'm using is just https://web.whatsapp.com/, which I suppose could be a problem, but there aren't any personal URLs as far as I'm aware. However, in developer tools using the element inspector I can easily access and read the DOM elements I'm interested in. I'm wondering if there's a way I can get this source directly using java/perl/python.

I'm also looking to do this as a learning project, so preferably would like to stay away from tools such as jsoup and such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`selenium.webdriver`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) in python. Something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
html = browser.page_source
```

If you want to get *your own* whatsapp page, you should use selenium to log into the site before getting the page_source.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Is there no way to download the current html from the element inspector though? Because the element inspector is giving me what I want, but I don't wanna go into it every time to check if a single word is there.

Comment: you can just right click on the page and select "show page source" I believe

Comment: Yeah, but the source I get is more general. It probably gets some information from the backend, I can only get the information I want from the element inspector unfortunately. If I go into elem. inspector and click "copy outer HTML" I get exactly what I want but I don't want to do that every time, since I'm trying to see if the content is changing.

Comment: So like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkrZD13OU8M
Except I don't wanna click that button every 5 minutes :D